# Using numbers and underscore in object literal keys causes error in Internet Explorer < 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have an object where I cache some HTML. It looks something like this:

```
MyNamespace.container.cache = {};
// add members
MyNamespace.container.cache['CAT_01'] = $('<SOME_HTML>');
MyNamespace.container.cache['CAT_02'] = $('<SOME_HTML>');
// ... produces
MyNamespace.container.cache = {
    'CAT_01': $('<SOME_HTML>'),
    'CAT_01': $('<SOME_HTML>')
};
```

This of course works in all browser except for IE<9.

When assigning new members to my cache object I get the following error:

**"SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery-1.6.2.min.js, line 17 character 29113"**

Strangley it works if I remove the namespace and container and assigns it to a global variabel like such.

```
var cache = {};
cache['CAT_01'] = $('<SOME_HTML>');
```

It also works if I remove the underscore from the key.

```
MyNamespace.container.cache['CAT02'] = $('<SOME_HTML>');
```

Unfortunately, that's not an option in my case.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help in advance.

/E

Comment: What is '<SOME HTML>'?  The error looks like it is thrown in jQuery...

Comment: It doesn't need to be html. Any value assigned throws the same error.

Comment: Are MyNamespace and MyNamespace.container already declared?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a namespace collision with the `MyNamespace.container.cache` property and the `jQuery.cache` property which occurs when the [jQuery expando is appended to the element](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8539) for IE. Try renaming `MyNamespace.container.cache` to `MyNamespace.container.memo` or filing a bug similar to these:

- [JSON bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8108)
- [noConflict bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6842)